# how to lsearch in list always match

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

I want match search from a list. I have dir names example:

```
blabla.aa
cc.oiwerwer
asfd.Dd.asoiwer
```

and I want to check if it is in the list (upper case should be ignored).

```
bind pub "-|-" !tt tt
proc tt {nick host handle channel arg} {

    set name [lindex [split $arg] 0]
    set groups {aa BB Cc DD Ee Ff gg hh}

    if {[lsearch -inline $groups $name] != -1} {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :match name $name"
    }
}
```

No matter what I write, it always says match...

Regards

Comment: What is the value of `$arg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to know if any element of the list `groups` matches the dir name examples. If that's so, then you should use a loop with [`string match`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M35):

```
bind pub "-|-" !tt tt
proc tt {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set name [lindex [split $arg] 0]
    set groups {aa BB Cc DD Ee Ff gg hh}

    foreach group $groups {
        if {[string match -nocase *$group* $name]} {
            putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$name matched $group"
            break
        }
    }
}
```

[codepad test](http://codepad.org/aFdPtxdQ)

Answer (score 0):

You specified the "-inline" parameter to lsearch. It returns the match or empty string. So, it is always doesn't equal to -1. Try to remove the "-inline" parameter. Also, probably you want to use the "-exact" parameter.

Reference: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm

Comment: when i use -inline then is only a match when $name BB is exactly matches, with BB.oiwerwer dont work

Comment: it is not possible to use simple `lsearch` for your templates. You should loop through all components in your `$name`. For example: `foreach part [split $name .] { if { [lsearch -exact $groups $part] != -1 } { putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :...."; break } }`

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange for your list of things to be all in one case (e.g., lower case) then you can use `[string tolower]` and the `in` operator to do the search. This is simpler than `lsearch` as it produces a clean binary result:

```
proc tt {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set name [lindex [split $arg] 0]
    set groups {aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh}

    if {[string tolower $name] in $groups} {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :match name $name"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but piecing together some clues, you might want:

```
set channels {
    blabla.aa
    cc.oiwerwer
    asfd.Dd.asoiwer
}
set groups {aa BB Cc DD Ee Ff gg hh}

foreach group $groups {
    set idx [lsearch -nocase $channels "*$group*"]
    if {$idx != -1} {
        puts "$group -> [lindex $channels $idx]"
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
aa -> blabla.aa
Cc -> cc.oiwerwer
DD -> asfd.Dd.asoiwer
```

Or, much more terse is:

```
lsearch -inline -all -nocase -regexp $channels [join $groups |]
```

```
blabla.aa cc.oiwerwer asfd.Dd.asoiwer
```